# How can I submit a spark application with different languages?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, spark-submit

As you might know in Zeppelin, in each cell we can define the interpreter separately e.g. pyspark, sql or spark. In my current scripts, I use a mix of languages and interpreters like this:

```
%spark2.pyspark

# constant parameters
#
FALSE_TRUE_PAIRS_RATIO = 1
NUM_TREES = 200
TRAIN_DATA_RATIO = 0.8
TEST_DATA_RATIO = 1 - TRAIN_DATA_RATIO

%spark2

// read data
//
val basepath = "/kafka-connect/topics/v1/year=2020"
spark.read
 .option("basePath", basepath)
 .parquet(basepath + "/month={07}")
 .createOrReplaceTempView("jul_data")

%spark2.spark

// extract page view data for medscape users in LA 
//
sql("""select * from jul_data
        where countryname='United States' and 
              cityname='New York' and 
              """).createOrReplaceTempView("raw_data")

%spark2.sql

-- just to view data
--
select * from raw_data
```

How can I submit a spark application for this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `sbt` project that assembles a jar, where you put the logic inside. With the assembled jar, you can do `spark-submit` command. See [example](https://github.com/Jackgmlin/mini-spark-with-sbt) of `sbt` project.